# Redirect по клику на ссылке записи

Tags: php, wordpress

Подскажите, как сделать редирект на определённую страницу, когда делается клик на названии записи? Нужно сделать обработчик хука the_permalink.
Допустим на главной странице при выводе списка постов, и при клике на любое название постов нужно сделать редирект на нужную страницу.
Как создать такой обработчик?

Comment: если вам необходимо обрабатывать событие кликов по элементам, то это реализуется средствами js, а не php и вордпресс-хуков

Comment: та нет, можно и с помощью хуков. Я уже нашёл как это делается, с помощью хука post_type_link